# How to speed up MySQLl loading from dump file?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysqldump

I'm using mysqld  Ver 5.7.25-0 in Ubuntu 16.04. I dumped from AWS Relational Database Service (RDS) with `mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --max_allowed_packet 1G` ... and now when I tried to load the dump with the command: `mysql -u <mu_user_name> -p<my_pwd>  <mu_db_name> < /mnt/rds.sql` I got stuck for almost 5 days. How long should it take and how can I speed up the processes? The rds.sql dump file size is 254G. btw I redirect the datadir of MySQL with symlink according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-using-a-symlink).

Comment: Which machine is your `mysql` running on?  What is the ping time between it and the AWS machine?

Comment: my point is to reduce the restore time , the dumping take about 1-2 hours fom Aurora MySQL aws RDS . i am talking about loading from the memory (.sql files to mysqld), i am using AWS m4.large instance type with 2048 GiB

Comment: I am trying to find out if the .sql files are being copied a long distance over the network.

Comment: they are , but they are not my bottleneck , i copy the tables locally to my vm and the restore from them take a long time.

Comment: Do `wc /mnt/rds.sql` - That will give you a clue of how long it takes to read every byte of the file.  Obviously, the loading cannot go faster than that.

Comment: i timed it with time command in Linux :                                                           `real    149m21.369s
user    82m49.724s
sys     1m44.844s` , so the insert to the tables  should take 149 minutes ?

Comment: At least 149 minutes.  OK 5 days is a lot more than that, so it is not _just_ disk speed that is the issue.  Do you have a lot of indexes on the tables?  Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the largest table.